# What should we do with "comments as answers" in review now?

Tags: support, low-quality-posts, review, comments-as-answers

The "comment, not an answer" comment in the Recommend Deletion box has had its title changed to "**This is commentary on another post, not an answer**". So how should we handle "comments to the current question posted as answers" in review now?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming here that the confusion lies in "another post"? If so, this does not indicate "another question" or anything of that nature. Each entry, be it the original question or any of its answers, can be considered "a post".

Therefore the "another post" in the title simply indicates *"This is commentary on either the question or one of the answers, not an answer in and of itself"*. At  least, that is how I understand it.

As a result, you can use it as you always would have.

Comment: In that case I think it should say __This is commentary on the question or another post, not an answer__ just to be clear. And given the comment actually added, I believe you're right.

Comment: Yeah, I admit it can seem somewhat confusing. I don't know the reason behind this particular change.